# How can I check if my Laravel homepage is up and running with cURL?

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-8, monitoring, health-monitoring

I am trying to do an uptime check of my Laravel application.
Essentially, I want to be able to login, and check that the home pages has loaded successfully via curl or similar.

I am using the below curl command:

```
curl -v -X POST -F 'email=myemail@domain.com&password=my_password' https://myurl.com/login
```

When I run this, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed exception page in my response.

When I login via the browser, I have made the following observations in my network inspector:

1st request: POST 302 - https://myurl.com/login
2nd request: GET 302 - https://myurl.com/
3rd request: GET 200 - https://myurl.com/ - my homepage is now loaded

I am unsure if there is a way to follow this in curl, or if this is the normal behaviour of Laravel login, or if some custom behaviour we have is causing this?

Is there a better way for me to validate that the homepage is up and running myself or with any suggested external services?

Comment: Are any other curl requests not working? Or only specifically this one?

Comment: Specifically this one, if I use `curl -L  -v -X GET https://lmysite.com` I get the HTML of my login page returned

Comment: do a `php artisan route:list`, and check if login route is GET or POST, or both

Comment: I have both
`GET|HEAD mysite.com/login login › Auth\LoginController@handleLoginForm
 POST      mysite.com/login Auth\LoginController@handleLoginRequest
`

Comment: What happens if you send same request but GET?

Comment: Make sure you also have "multipart/form-data" as login form in your blade file

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few cURL checks you can use to see if your Laravel homepage is operational:

To submit a POST request to the /login endpoint, use the -X POST option. If the login is successful, this will imitate the login procedure and return a 200 OK response.

```
curl -X POST -F 'email=myemail@domain.com&password=my_password' https://myurl.com/login
```

To follow redirection, use the -L option. This will guarantee that cURL adheres to any redirection that the server returns. This is required because, once you have successfully logged in, the login process usually redirects you to the homepage.

```
curl -L -X POST -F 'email=myemail@domain.com&password=my_password' https://myurl.com/login
```

Get verbose output by selecting the -v option. The HTTP request and response headers will be displayed, which might be useful for troubleshooting.

```
curl -v -X POST -F 'email=myemail@domain.com&password=my_password' https://myurl.com/login
```

Your Laravel application may be set up to only accept POST requests to the /login endpoint if you continue to receive a 405 Method Not Allowed error. To send a GET request in this situation, you must use the -X GET option.

```
curl -X GET -F 'email=myemail@domain.com&password=my_password' https://myurl.com/login
```

Please check these things. It's helpful.

Comment: Thanks but almost identical to what I have tried and still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

do you have this `RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=302]` in your htaccess? if so, try to change it to `RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=307]`and see if it works or not.